# Computed return type based on parameters

Tags: node.js, typescript

Say I have a function like this:

```
  static async getPets({ petType, inverseOrder }: { petType: string; inverseOrder?: boolean }) {
    const [petsFound, totalFound] = await getPetsByType(petType, inverseOrder);
    return {
      [petType]: petsFound, // array topped to 20 results
      totalFound // count all found without limit of 20
    };
  }
```

I want the return type of this function to be computed based on the `petType` parameter, which can be any string, so that:

- `getPets({ petType: 'dogs' })` has return type `{ dogs: any[], totalFound: number }`
- `getPets({ petType: 'cats' })` has return type `{ cats: any[], totalFound: number }`
- etc.

The current implementation has the return type `{ [x: string]: any; totalFound: any; }` which is not very useful since it doesn't check that the key returned is the same as the one used as param.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why not to use generics?

Comment: Because: _"An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type."_.

Comment: Fundamentally that's not a very usable return type anyway. Why not just `return { petsFound, totalFound }`?

Comment: Well, generics not for index signature but for the type of returned object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is optimized, but it works:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMAFYgZwCEBPAFWoAcEAKJjepgLnnIxi1QEANPAEA3EDHIgA8jFAwA-NwBGOHBBBRUASm4kYOALZZpAHgDa26hYC6I1MiMrJtgHwBuALAAoXxkYEAEEAdygsDBBgM1o3eABeeFp4EAAPSNRgcngDY1MQMwFESXgAVTjFMvhuWm8-HwCmeABxYjIMcgAlEHJkCAwYlPSQTOzefkE4xIBvX3h4CwBrUXxaW25Q8Mjo7oxkGFQOAsaQHERCNooaI7c3CwAGWzqAX3gAMnhZn3mMHAwoCAAMRwaGAGzCESiZl2+0OgTMJzOF1IVzogVuFgAjE9fM86r4oORqOgkGhMLh8EQUR14IM0hksjw+AICG5mNN4GwjiJxJJpHIFPBntwvvMuYEanV5rypLJ5JJlPA1BotKgXnocoYTOZWtSuj0+gNYnFRfAwHheAs2ORgaCRL9-kCQZlbAl4FAIRhke0qGimKxiNyVhJZQLJDopfA4HsDp85vMrYHAutORRbZkhPGfn8AengJnvkL3dldT7ur1+jFPLjfASiSSUOhsHh4EZwvhmDo44XzahLXAK17Eh6tt6KOzxVx4AByAhYGBQRDFac81Ah-nymDcRAA6TPCPx3vkFUAOggOAIzAHhpPc4XS5AZ5GBAwAAsEvFEtf+ieHbnncAEbwAA9MB8A4Ish4Wqe56Xt+GAnmAUAIZoghvh+X4Gj+f5OqCQGgfAACiMCGFumo4EwMABDOSEYNO8DADgPTwKgfxDKYXoticM6lhQ5aGmYABEd6LsUgluNOJ7MAATAAzLJACcOi4kAA)

```ts
declare function getPetsByType (petType: string, inverseOrder?: boolean): Promise<[any[], number]>;

type Awaited<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T;

type GetPetsResult<T extends string> = {
  [k in T]: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getPetsByType>>[0];
} & {
  totalFound: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getPetsByType>>[1];
};

async function getPets <T extends string>({ petType, inverseOrder }: {
  petType: T;
  inverseOrder?: boolean;
}): Promise<GetPetsResult<T>> {
  const [petsFound, totalFound] = await getPetsByType(petType, inverseOrder);
  return {
    [petType]: petsFound,
    totalFound,
  } as GetPetsResult<T>;
}

async function main () {
  const result = await getPets({petType: 'giraffe', inverseOrder: false});
  console.log(result.giraffe.length === result.totalFound); // ok
  console.log(result.cat.length === result.totalFound); // Error: Property 'cat' does not exist on type 'GetPetsResult<"giraffe">'.(2339)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This works, although I did not use the Awaited type. Not sure what it does

Comment: That's not a thorough implementation of `Awaited` anyway. You can read more about the upcoming implementation here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements

Answer (score 0):

Not getting into implementation details of `Promise` and focusing only on the return type based on the parameter passed, you could do the following:

```
// transform generic into literal type
type StringLiteral<T> = T extends string ? string extends T ? never : T : never;

// define function
function getPets<Key>({ petType }: { petType: StringLiteral<Key>}): Record<StringLiteral<Key>, number[]> & {totalFound: number;} {
    return {
        [petType] : [1, 2, 3],
        totalFound: 123
    } as  Record<StringLiteral<Key>, number[]> & {totalFound: number}
}

// pass in 'petType' and get a a return type based on whatever you defined on that param
const {} = getPets({petType: 'cats'}) // return type : Record<"cats", number[]>
```

Comment: Thanks, very concise! I would give you a point but it doesn't let me...

Comment: No worries mate, I'm happy to help anyway ;)